# Unable to get access token from Google for Service Account

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to configure an application able to work with Gmail API. As you know to work with it we must have an access token. There are several way of requesting this token, but for my needs it should be a service account, because in future this program code will be inside the Windows Service... (so, there is no opportunity to receive the token manually by redirecting from Google URL, only a web-request and response is a way out)

So, what I have done already:

1. Created new project (in Google Cloud Platform);
2. Created new service account in this project (according to the steps mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount );
3. Generated and downloaded *.P12 key;
4. Enabled domain-wide delegation [before step 4 as were suggested in many similar questions];
5. Authorized the scope "https://mail.google.com/" in G Suite admin account for correct Client Id (according to the steps mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority );
6. Used such simple code for authorization and requesting token:

```
            const string serviceAccountEmail = "***test@oauthtester-271011.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
            const string serviceAccountCertPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OAuthTester\OAuthTester\bin\Debug\oauthtester-271011-bd2cced31ea5.p12";
            const string serviceAccountCertPassword = "notasecret";
            const string userEmail = "***oauthtest@***.com";

            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                serviceAccountCertPath,
                serviceAccountCertPassword,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { GoogleScope.ImapAndSmtp.Name }, //"https://mail.google.com/"
                    User = userEmail
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));


            credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

Unfortunately, I'm facing with an error:

```
Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.
```

I have also tried:

1. To change serviceAccountEmail to ClientId;
2. To create, remove and add again the Authorized access in G Suite for the same Client Id;
3. To delete and create another service account and then Authorize new Client Id in G Suite.

Unfortunately, each time I'm facing with the same error. Maybe somebody guesses what I do wrong?

Comment: Hello Andrii, it could be a propagation problem. It could take up to 48h for authorization to propagate through the domain. When did you make the last change to your service account?

Comment: Hi @Allesandro, I had done the update last week (on Thursday or Friday), checked then and also had checked it again today (thinking about some kind of time issue), before re-adding the same clientId and removing and recreating the service account...

Comment: So today you updated the configuration, right?

Comment: Yes @Alessandro, but it was a second time...

Comment: Ok, give it a try tomorrow to be sure that is not the problem.

Comment: Hi @Alessandro. 48h have already passed, so, I have just tested again - unfortunately the result is the same: ...TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:""...

Comment: Hello Andrii, in this case, try to contact the GSuite support: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213